# Update Immutable.Map

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I would like to change the `active` for item 1 to true, while also setting others (some hundred) `active` to false.

```
import {Map, Record} from 'immutable';

const initialState = new Map({
  0: new Record({
    id: 0,
    name: 'foo',
    active: true,
  }),
  1: new Record({
    id: 1,
    name: 'bar',
    active: false,
  }),
  2: new Record({
    id: 2,
    name: 'baz',
    active: false,
  }),
});

const TARGET = 1;

const newState = initialState.merge(
  initialState.map((value) => {
    if (value.id === TARGET) {
      return value.set('active', true);
    } else if (value.active) {
      return value.set('active', false);
    }
    return value;
  })
);
```

Is it possible to do it easiest or better? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the `merge` part, setting the `newState` to the result of the `mapping` function is enough. Other than that, your implementation is the easiest I can think of.

Comment: @tiagohngl you are right, the merge is unnecessary. tks!